# how to view, from python, the list of files that are printing

Tags: python, printing

I've done a class in Python to print a kind of receipt in a EPSON POS printer. I've used `win32ui`, `win32con` and `win32print` modules.

But I want to see the status of the documents that I send to print, at least know how many are left and what is being printed.

My code, if you want to see it:

```
class Lucida:
    def __init__(self, size=10, weight=win32con.FW_NORMAL, italic=False, underline=False):
        self.name = 'Lucida Console'
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
        self.italic = italic
        self.underline = underline

    def get_Ob(self):
        return win32ui.CreateFont(self.get_dict())

    def get_dict(self):
        return {'name':self.name,
                'height':self.size*20,
                'weight': self.weight,
                'italic':self.italic,
                'underline':self.underline}
    def change(self, size=None, weight=None, italic=None, underline=None):
        if type(size) == dict:
            if 'size'      in size: self.size      = size['size']
            if 'weight'    in size: self.weight    = size['weight']
            if 'italic'    in size: self.italic    = size['italic']
            if 'underline' in size: self.underline = size['underline']
        else:
            if not size      == None: self.size      = size
            if not weight    == None: self.weight    = weight
            if not italic    == None: self.italic    = italic
            if not underline == None: self.underline = underline

    def get_width(self, text):
        tan = 0.6005 #is the proportion width/height of the Lucida Console font
        w=self.size*len(text)*0.6005*20
        return w


class Printer:
    def __init__(self, printer_name=win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()):
        self.printer_name = printer_name

        self.dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
        self.dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
        self.dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
        self.pt_to_next_line = 0
        self.font=Lucida()
        self.started = False
        self.lmargin = 0
        self.tmargin = 0

    def WriteLine(self, line, to_right = 0, to_next_line = True):
        '''Print a line
        line -> str: the string to print
        to_right -> int: the margin from left border of the sheet
        to_next_line -> bool: if wanna jump to the next line or continue on same
        '''
        x = int(56.7*self.lmargin+to_right)
        y = int(-self.pt_to_next_line-self.tmargin)
        self.dc.TextOut(x, y, line)
        if to_next_line:
            self.pt_to_next_line+=self.font.size*20

    def WriteLineSec(self, sec):
        '''print a row of text, making changes described in sec.
        sec is a list of:
        str : String to print in the row
        dict: some change on font. it can contain, or not:
            {
                'size': int|None
                'weight': int|None
                'italic': bool|None
                'underline': bool|None
            }
            None for no change.
        '''
        to_right=0
        Max=self.font.size
        for item in sec:
            if type(item) == dict:
                self.SelectFont(item)
                if self.font.size>Max:
                    Max=self.font.size
            else:
                self.WriteLine(item, to_right, False)
                to_right+=self.font.get_width(item)
        self.pt_to_next_line+=Max*20

    def WriteText(self, text):
        '''print some text, splitting by lines and printing each line'''
        for linea in text.splitlines():
            if len(linea)>0:
                if linea[-1]=="\n":
                    linea=linea[:-1]
            self.WriteLine(linea)

    def SelectFont(self, size=None, weight=None, italic=None, underline=None):
        self.font.change(size, weight, italic, underline)
        self.dc.SelectObject(self.font.get_Ob())

    def StartDoc(self, title):
        if not self.started:
            self.dc.StartDoc(title)
            self.started=True
        else:
            raise

    def EndDoc(self):
        if self.started:
            self.dc.EndDoc()
            self.started=False
        else:
            raise

    def SetLeftMargin(self, margin):
        self.lmargin=margin

    def SetTopMargin(self, margin):
        self.tmargin=margin
```

Comment: Obligatory style guide suggestion: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example (http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32print.html):

```
import win32print
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
# starts at 0 and enumerates/iterates 1st job
# job info defaults to JOB_INFO_1 and is not included
win32print.EnumJobs(handle,0,1)
```

See for details: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32print__EnumJobs_meth.html

Output:

```
({'Status': 8, 'pPrinterName': 'HP LaserJet Professional P1102w', 'pDocument': '
new  1', 'Submitted': <PyTime:8/7/2014 5:28:46 PM>, 'JobId': 3, 'Priority': 1, '
pUserName': 'Guest', 'pStatus': None, 'PagesPrinted': 0, 'Position': 1, 'TotalPa
ges': 0, 'pDatatype': 'IMF', 'pMachineName': '\\\\[fe80::c1c2:3886:cba0:d92a]'},
)
```